# JavaScript settimeout is not working

Tags: javascript, php, runtime-error

This script is throwing this error every half second:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. signals.js:9
req.onreadystatechange signals.js:9
update_table signals.js:26
req.onreadystatechange
```

This is signals.js - I want it to reload every 5 seconds and if there is new content, to trigger the "Sound" alert.

```
    function update_table()
{

    var old_table = document.getElementById('signals').innerHTML;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.status == 200)
    {
        if(req.readyState == 4)
        {
            var new_table = req.responseText;
            alert(old_table);
            alert(new_table);
            if(old_table != new_table)
            {
                //play sound
                alert("Sound!");
            }
            alert("Refresh!");
            setTimeout(update_table, 5000);
        }
        }
    }
    var link = "table.php?refresh=true";

    req.open("GET", link, false);
    req.send();

}
```

Comment: You probably want `setTimeout(update_table, 5000);` (skip parentheses)

Comment: Changed it, not I've got this but the InvalidStateError remains sadly:

Comment: @kamituel sorry 2 bother.. but did someone named brojisjas... or whatever had just posted a comment and deleted it ?? o__O

Comment: @LiamSchnell - do you know which line causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

First check if the req.readyState equals 4 and then check if the req.status equals 200.
The HTTP status code isn't set before the request is processed, so you can't use it before the readyState equals 4.

You can check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) for more info about the onreadystatechange event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check whether `req.readyState` equals to `4` (means `DONE`), and only then check for `req.status`:

```
function update_table() {
    var old_table = document.getElementById('signals').innerHTML;

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {

        // Here: first check for readyState
        if(req.readyState === 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var new_table = req.responseText;
            alert(old_table);
            alert(new_table);
            if(old_table != new_table)
            {
                //play sound
                alert("Sound!");
            }
            alert("Refresh!");
            setTimeout(update_table, 5000);
        }
    }
    var link = "table.php?refresh=true";    

    req.open("GET", link, false);
    req.send();

}
```

See [XMLHttpRequest doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for details.